# Is it safe to store TwitterAPI access tokens in Session variables?

Tags: php, session, oauth, xss, twitter-oauth

Most sites instruct the access token and access token secret obtained via the Twitter API to be stored in $_SESSION.

On the other hand, however, we also see many sites that say "$_SESSION should not store sensitive information (credentials, etc.) because of the risk of XSS (cross-site scripting).

Is this a good way to do it?

> ```
> $_SESSION[ 'oauth_token' ] = $reply->oauth_token;
> $_SESSION[ 'oauth_token_secret' ] = $reply->oauth_token_secret;
> ```
>
> Quote from https://www.wabiapp.com/PronamaStudy/php/php_twitter_auth.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sensitive data storage in sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966282/sensitive-data-storage-in-sessions)